# redirect to HTTPS between multiple domains

Tags: https, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have two domains (e.g. domainone.com and domaintwo.com) and they are pointing to one website.
I have one ssl certificate for domainone.com.

I want to do auto-redirect to https for domainone.com.
I don't want to do auto-redirect to https for domaintwo.com coz I don't have ssl certificate for this domaintwo.com. I just want to open it with http.

the rule in url rewrite (IIS) is as below.

```
Match URL – Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Match URL – Using: Regular Expression
Pattern: (.*)

Condition Input: {HTTPS}
Check if input string: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: ^OFF$

Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
Redirect type: See Other (303)
```

now both of the domain names are auto-redirecting to https. Kindly help me how to do to auto-redirect to https for only domainone.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added one condition. Now it is working as I want.

```
Match URL – Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Match URL – Using: Regular Expression
Pattern: (.*)

Condition Input: {HTTPS}
Check if input string: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: ^OFF$
Condition Input: {HTTP_HOST}
Check if input string: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: domainone.com

Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
Redirect type: See Other (303)
```